# Slickgrid - How to update data in the dataview?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have an instance where I need to essentially wipe out all data in the dataview and provide the dataview with a new set of data.

Here is what I have currently. :

```
GridView.beginUpdate();
GridView.setItems(sortedData);
GridView.endUpdate();
GridView.refresh();
```

I have tried these and numerous other functions. :

```
grid.invalidate();
grid.render();
grid.invalidateAllRows();
```

The crazy thing is that when I start the dataview (gridview) starts with a count of 17.

SortedData has a count of 91, and after setItems the count is 84.  I am not sure how that is occurring.  I have read every article and stackoverflow entry about this dataview topic of removal and addition and tried them all.

Thoroughly confused, as I have been trying to figure this out for a while, hoping someone has run into this situation previously.  Currently, thinking that it may be due to something I am subscribed to.

@Kzahel I actually have a subscription set like so. :

```
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            grid.updateRowCount();
            grid.render();
        });
```

The above is actually handling my row count updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my solution. :

```
GridView.beginUpdate();
GridView.setItems(sortedData);
GridData = sortedData;
GridView.endUpdate();
GridView.refresh();
```

I had functions using GridData in other areas causing a multitude of issues.

Comment: Do you mean GridView.data = sortedData ? What is happening here? Can you link to a jsfiddle maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try grid.updateRowCount()
I also have problems with slickgrid and dynamic content. But most of the problems went away after calling that function. See:
https://github.com/kzahel/jstorrent/blob/master/examples/grid.js#L172